# c++ - <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, function, templates

In my class called `Mat`, I want to have a function which takes another function as a parameter. Right now I have the 4 functions below, but I get an error in when calling print(). The second line gives me an error, but I don't understand why, since the first one works. The only difference is function `f` is not a member of the class `Mat`, but `f2` is.
The failure is: `error: no matching function for call to Mat::test( < unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'`

```
template <typename F>
int Mat::test(F f, int v){
    return f(v);
}

int Mat::f2(int x){
    return x*x;
}

int f(int x){
    return x*x;
}

void Mat::print(){
    printf("%d\n",test(f ,5));    // works
    printf("%d\n",test(f2 ,5));    // does not work
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is `f2` static or not?

Comment: Try changing the printf call to printf("%d\n", test(Mat::f2, 5));

Comment: Do you have more than one overload of `f2`?

Comment: Barry gave you a working fix, however, I'm curious as to the actual reason that his fix works. Would you mind trying the line of code I gave you in previous comment?

Comment: @2to1mux. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/addr-of-memfn.html. Who knew?

Comment: -1 because 1) it does not have a proper complete testcase 2) it does not say what compiler is used.

Comment: @2to1mux I've already tried what you said, that didn't help. But if I change make f2 a static member function it works.

Comment: @stardust_ thanks! That makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 49):

The type of `pointer-to-member-function` is different from `pointer-to-function`.

The type of a function is different depending on whether it is an ordinary function or a **non-static member function** of some class:

```
int f(int x);
the type is "int (*)(int)" // since it is an ordinary function
```

And

```
int Mat::f2(int x);
the type is "int (Mat::*)(int)" // since it is a non-static member function of class Mat
```

Note: if it's a static member function of class Fred, its type is the same as if it were an ordinary function: `"int (*)(char,float)"`

> In C++, member functions have an implicit parameter which points to
>   the object (the this pointer inside the member function). Normal C
>   functions can be thought of as having a different calling convention
>   from member functions, **so the types of their pointers
>   (pointer-to-member-function vs pointer-to-function) are different and
>   incompatible.** C++ introduces a new type of pointer, **called a
>   pointer-to-member, which can be invoked only by providing an object**.
>
> NOTE: do not attempt to "cast" a pointer-to-member-function into a
>   pointer-to-function; the result is undefined and probably disastrous.
>   E.g., **a pointer-to-member-function is not required to contain the
>   machine address of the appropriate function.** As was said in the last
>   example, if you have a pointer to a regular C function, use either a
>   top-level (non-member) function, or a static (class) member function.

More on this [Here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html) and [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/addr-of-memfn.html).

Comment: But this doesn't explain why the template can't resolve it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore This is how I understood it. The compiler expects a type that provides a `call operator` or sees if it can find a function that matches  `int f(int)` reachable from Mat::Test. And according the the description above `pointer-to-member-function vs pointer-to-function are different and incompatible`. So it will not match `this->f2` as a function. This is just my understanding. I didn't even know about this before today :)

Comment: Links seem to be dead.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that `f2` is a method on `Mat`, while `f` is just a free function. You can't call `f2` by itself, it needs an instance of `Mat` to call it on. The easiest way around this might be:

```
printf("%d\n", test([=](int v){return this->f2(v);}, 5));
```

The `=` there will capture `this`, which is what you need to call `f2`.

Comment: Since f2 and print are both member functions of Mat, isn't print allowed to call f2 without referencing a Mat object?

Comment: Wow, this works (with a few tweaks from the original code). +1 from me

Comment: -1 . the error message says that the error happens because of an overloaded function, and not because the function template's function call syntax is wrong (which is what you say).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That isn't what he is saying. He's saying that f2 can only be called via an instance of a Mat object. This solution solves the issue (Although, I actually think it solves the original compiler error for a different reason than the one stated by Barry).

Comment: I think in this case the compiler error is not the best. `f2` just isn't a function, `&Mat::f2` is. If you tried to pass in that instead, you'd get a compile error about invalid call syntax.

Comment: This also gives me an error: "no matching function for call to 'Mat::test(Mat::print()::< lambda(int)>, int)'"

Comment: Minor nit: according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture):

`The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either capture default is present. If implicitly captured, it is always captured by reference, even if the capture default is =. [[The implicit capture of *this when the capture default is = is deprecated. (since C++20)]]`. So the capture should use `[&]`.