# How to use template in the class itself in c++?

Tags: c++

RequestS want to use ReportUrlThread's function(send) .ReportUrlThread is a template class.

It look like below the code is that "request->process(reportUrl->send);",
how can I achieve it?

The codes below can't be through compilation.

```
int main()
{
    typedef Threadpool<RequestS> ThreadpoolDealFromBS2;
    ThreadpoolDealFromBS2 threadpool;
    ReportUrlReq* req = new ReportUrlReq();

    threadpool.appendReportHiUrl(req);

}

class RequestS {
    public:
      RequestS()
      {


      }
      virtual ~RequestS()
      {
      }

      virtual void process(void (*send)(bool &exp))
        {
             log(Info, "RequestS...fun");
        }
};

class ReportUrlReq:public RequestS {
    public:
        ReportUrlReq();
        ~ReportUrlReq();
        virtual void process(void (*send)(bool &exp))
        {
             log(Info, "ReportUrlReq...fun");
        }

};

template< typename T >
class ReportUrlThread {
    public:
        ReportUrlThread(uint32_t id)
        {
        }
        virtual ~ReportUrlThread()
        {
        }

    void send(bool &exp)
    {

    }

    Threadpool< T >* threadpool;
};

template< typename T >
class Threadpool
{
public:

    Threadpool( std::vector<ReportUrlThread<T>*>& reportUrl);
    ~Threadpool();
    bool appendReportHiUrl( T* request );
private:
    static void* reportWorker( void* arg );
    void reportRun(ReportUrlThread<T> *reportUrl);
    pthread_t* m_ReportUrlThreads;
};

template< typename T >
Threadpool< T >::Threadpool( std::vector<ReportUrlThread<T>*>& reportUrl)
{
    m_ReportUrlThreads = new pthread_t[reportUrlThreadNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ReportUrlThread<T> * reportUrlThread = reportUrl[i];

        reportUrlThread->threadpool =  this;

        if( pthread_create( m_ReportUrlThreads + i, NULL, reportWorker, reportUrlThread ) != 0 )
        {
            delete [] m_ReportUrlThreads;
            throw std::exception();
        }
        if( pthread_detach( m_ReportUrlThreads[i] ) )
        {
            delete [] m_ReportUrlThreads;
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }

}

template< typename T >
void* Threadpool< T >::reportWorker( void* arg )
{
    ReportUrlThread<T>* reportUrl =  (ReportUrlThread<T>*)arg;
    Threadpool* pool = reportUrl->threadpool;
    pool->reportRun(reportUrl);
    return pool;
}

template< typename T >
void Threadpool< T >::reportRun(ReportUrlThread<T> *reportUrl)
{
    while ( ! m_ReportStop )
    {
        m_ReportQueuestat.wait();
        m_ReportQueuelocker.lock();
        if ( m_ReportWorkqueue.empty() )
        {
            m_ReportQueuelocker.unlock();
            continue;
        }


        T* request = m_ReportWorkqueue.front();
        m_ReportWorkqueue.pop_front();

        reportDealNum++;
        m_ReportWorkqueueSize = m_ReportWorkqueue.size();


        request->process(reportUrl->send);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really the shortest code to demonstrate what you want? Would *you* be inclined to read so many lines of code to figure out what you are being asked?

Comment: I don't see any superclasses? `RequestS` is not a base class (in the above code) because nothing inherits from it.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, I have added some codes.It will be Clarity.

Comment: Added? My point was that your code sample is too long. It's not a [minimum, compile and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @erip I have edited my codes.It will be calrity.

Comment: @morenhei StoryTeller's point is that you've given _too much_ code.

Comment: @StoryTeller If you are a coder,the codes is clarity.

Comment: @morenhei Unfortunately you don't make the rules when asking for help on a site with defined guidelines... best of luck.

Comment: *"The codes"* are a mess that hides your problem. If you aren't going to make an effort to simmer your example down to something precise, I'm certainly not going to bother.

Comment: @erip  If I ditn't show the codes,it can't be explained.

Comment: [This is an MVCE](http://ideone.com/5wukJf).

Comment: It doesn't compile because none of the classes used inside main have been declared or defined by the time the compiler needs it.

Comment: @Flexo  I put the main function at the beginning,it just help you to understand the codes.It is shortest code.

Comment: @erip  please read my codes carefully,your codes are not I mean

Comment: @morenhei - it doesn't help at all because it shows *a totally different error* to the one you're actually stuck with

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is, that you're passing the memberfunction `reportUrl->send` to `request->process` expecting an ordinary function. But a member function needs an instance of its class! If `send` depends on members of `ReportUrlThread`, you might want to pass an instance of `ReportUrlThread` (or a derived class implementing `send`):

```
virtual void process(ReportUrlThread<RequestS> *RepUrlThReqS) {
    bool exp;
    RepUrlThReqS->send(exp);
    // ...
}
```

If not, you might want to use a static function:

```
static void send(bool &exp) {
    // ...
}
```

You might even want to use a lambda function (which is quite a bit hacky here):

```
class RequestS {
public:
    virtual void process(void(*send)(bool &exp, void* instance), void *instance) {
        bool exp;
        send(exp, instance);
    }
};

template< typename T >
class ReportUrlThread {
public:
    void send(bool &exp) { }
};

int main() {
    ReportUrlThread<RequestS> *reportUrl = new ReportUrlThread<RequestS>;
    RequestS *request = new RequestS;
    request->process(
        [](bool &exp, void* reportUrlA) {
        ((ReportUrlThread<RequestS> *)reportUrlA)->send(exp);
    }, reportUrl);
}
```

And many more possibilities...
It's up to you to decide, which is the best solution in your case.

Comment: Sir, you're wrong and your example is not valid C++.

Comment: @moren hei: nikitoz commented on an already deleted example, which was in fact wrong... (-;

Comment: @Corylus    request->process(reportUrl->send);  it is wrong here.But that is what I want

Comment: @moren hei: You mean, it results in syntax errors? Which Compiler (Version?) are you using? MSVC2015 can compile this code.

Comment: @Corylus I compile this code in ubuntu,gcc version 4.3.3. the compile error are lThread<T>*> >&, std::vector<ReportUrlThread<T>*, std::allocator<ReportUrlThread<T>*> >&, std::vector<ReportUrlThread<T>*, std::allocator<ReportUrlThread<T>*> >&, int) [with T = RequestS]'
BS2Server.cpp:153:   instantiated from here
Threadpool.h:972: error: no matching function for call to 'RequestS::process(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Comment: @morenhei: That says it all! 'reportUrl->send' is a member function, but 'request->process' expects an ordinary function. The code excerpt can be compiled, because the compiler omits the never used function 'reportRun'. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841338/c-unresolved-overloaded-function-type).

Comment: @Corylus - I have read the question .I know your means,but how to solve my issue ?