# C++ list::sort <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, list

I'm having trouble with c++, trying to sort a playlist with my own functions but it is not working.. I checked many posts speaking about a possible similar problem but I couldn't find any solution. ([c++ - <unresolved overloaded function type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841338/c-unresolved-overloaded-function-type) -- I'm having the same error as in this post but not sure to understand what to do then).

May I have a hint please? :)
Here is my function to compare, comp just compare strings in lowercase.

```
bool Playlist::byTitleAscend (Music *a, Music *b) { return comp(a->getTitle(), b->getTitle()); }
```

Then I try to sort my list with it and it throws an error :/

```
_musics.sort(byTitleAscend); // ERROR, TODO: why ?
```

I hope it's clear enough!

In the documentation they use const & but it's also said that if we don't change the objects it's not necessary.

Error:

> MusicReader/playlist.cpp:148: error: no matching function for call to 'std::list(Music*)::sort(unresolved overloaded function type)'
>            _musics.sort(byTitleAscend);

I replaced < by ( because it was not showing.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error text. One thing that looks odd to me is [compared with the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/), you are using `Music *a, Music *b` as parameters instead of `Music const *a, Music const *b` or `Music const &a, Music const &b` - I cannot say which without seeing the declaration of `_musics`.

Comment: I suspect that `byTitleAscend` isn't static.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it works now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there was several errors, 
@cokceken was right because I forgot to add the scope and the real problem was that I forgot to scope the comp function too ..

And then without putting the function as static it couldn't work neither, so thanks to @molbdnilo too !

Answer (score 1):

```
_musics.sort(byTitleAscend);
```

line should be in Playlist class scope. If it is not, the line should be

```
_musics.sort(Playlist::byTitleAscend);
```