# Class constructor <unresolved overloaded function type> when trying to pass an aggregated object's method to its class method

Tags: c++, overloading, class-constructors

I'm writing a custom library sourcing [PubSubClient](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient). Everything went well, expect for integrating the callback function in my library.

I get the following errors from the Arduino IDE:

> Error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::setCallback("<"unresolved overloaded function type">")' client -> setCallback(callback);
>
> ...
>
> Users/Mark/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:121:18:
>   note: PubSubClient&
>   PubSubClient::setCallback(std::function)
>           PubSubClient& setCallback(MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE);

In my xxx.h file I declared:

```
class Iotdevice {

  private:
    ...
    PubSubClient* client;
    ...

  public:
    ...
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
    ...
}
```

In my xxx.cpp file I defined:

```
Iotdevice::Iotdevice() {
  ...
  client = new PubSubClient(*espClient);
  ...
}

void Iotdevice::callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {...}
```

, and I called:

```
void Iotdevice::setup() {
       ...
       client -> setCallback(callback);
       ...
}
```

I have tried a lot of variations, but I can't seem to solve it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you please post the code section where you call `setCallback`?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Another question: do you have other member functions called `callback` in your `Iotdevice` class?

Comment: @themiurge Thanks for your fast response! I edited my question above. There is only one member function called callback.

Comment: Two other things: First of all have you tried using `&callback`? Secondly, are you sure you can have callbacks to *member functions*? Because (non-static) member functions and non-member functions (or `static` member function) are not really compatible. A non-static member function needs an *object* to be called on. Are there functions to set the object to call the function on?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: from what I can see looking at the code the OP is trying to wrap, `setCallback` takes a `void (*callback)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)`. He's going to need some kind of dispatcher.

Comment: @MarkdeJonge: take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841338/c-unresolved-overloaded-function-type) (and the first answer) to understand what's happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried the ampersand like so `client -> setCallback(&callback);`, but I get the following error: 
/Users/Mark/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ClassStructure/ClassStructure.cpp:51:27: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Iotdevice::callback' [-fpermissive]
    client -> setCallback(&callback);

Comment: @themiurge looking into it now, thanks!

Comment: And if you follow the advice from GCC (you *did* read the error message? It tells you what to do), what happens then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I get the following errors, it can't seem to match it like this: /Users/Mark/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ClassStructure/ClassStructure.cpp:51:46: error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::setCallback(void (Iotdevice::*)(char*, byte*, unsigned int))'
    client -> setCallback(&Iotdevice::callback);

/Users/Mark/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:121:18: note: PubSubClient& PubSubClient::setCallback(std::function<void(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>)
    PubSubClient& setCallback(MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE);

Comment: So `setCallback` takes a `std::function` argument? Then I suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) *and* [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Using the last one (`std::bind`) is the solution to your problems. Both for the call to `setCallback` *and* for how to handle non-static member functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, reading it now!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
This finally solved the problem: `client -> setCallback([this](char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {   this->callback(topic, payload, length); });
`